# bulding setup javafx-gradle-plugin with inno-script-studio?

Tags: java, mysql, gradle, javafx, javafx-2

I'm working on a javafx project with `gradle`, but seems like there isn't a good documentation or web site or video on how create setup for rhis kinda javafx application, I mean I found a lots of samples around `ANT`and `MAVEN`, but

I was unable to found some good practices in gradle,
after that I downloadeded `inno-script-studio` but I don't know what to do to, at least create a jar file or executable file to make setup with.
here is the plug-in I use for javafx-gradle [javafx-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/FibreFoX/javafx-gradle-plugin), it says on the description:

> (Windows) EXE installers: Inno Setup

but I don't know how to do it

here is my `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'de.dynamicfiles.projects.gradle.plugins', name: 'javafx-gradle-plugin', version: '8.8.2'

    }
    repositories {

        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()

    }
}
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'java'
if (!hasProperty('mainClass')) {
    ext.mainClass = "Main.Launcher"
}
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies{
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.10'
    compile "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.0"
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jfoenix/jfoenix
    compile group: 'com.jfoenix', name: 'jfoenix', version: '1.6.0'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-gradle-plugin
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-gradle-plugin', version: '5.2.10.Final'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.2.10.Final'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-annotations
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-annotations', version: '3.5.6-Final'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '6.0.6'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j
    compile group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.17'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.jensd/fontawesomefx
    compile group: 'de.jensd', name: 'fontawesomefx', version: '8.9'
}
apply plugin: 'javafx-gradle-plugin'


jfx {
    appName = 'StudentManager'
    vendor = 'shaheen'
    // minimal requirement for jfxJar-task
    mainClass = "Main.Launcher"
}
```

*any tips, suggestions, samples, would be good, thank you*

Answer (score 1):

The [javafx-maven-plugin](https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin) and [javafx-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/FibreFoX/javafx-gradle-plugin) share the same underlying tool: the `javapackager` (previous known as javafxpackager) so all restrictions apply to these build-tool plugins.

When creating the native installer, a installer-script has to be used (.iss-file for InnoSetup, .wxs-file for WiX), therefor some internal stored preset is processed for this:
- for Inno Setup: https://github.com/teamfx/openjfx-8u-dev-rt/blob/master/modules/fxpackager/src/main/resources/com/oracle/tools/packager/windows/template.iss
- for WiX: https://github.com/teamfx/openjfx-8u-dev-rt/blob/master/modules/fxpackager/src/main/resources/com/oracle/tools/packager/windows/template.wxs

While the process of copying some files and creating the installer, special strings are replaced within these templates. To have this file being picked up while running the build-tool plugin, you have to store some iss/wxs-file at `src/main/deploy/windows/{appname}.iss/.wxs`, where `{appname}` is your project-specified "appName" (on gradle its mostly the root project name, on maven this defaults to `artifactId-version`, but can be overriden by appName-configuration). This works because there is a special "drop-in replacement"-mechanism used inside the javapackager.

To have a prepared/processed file, you have to set `verbose` to `true` (inside the jfx-block when using gradle and inside the configuration of the plugin when using maven), then all used files will be preserved inside the `%TEMP%`-folder.

If there is anything needed further, please comment this and I will add this to the answer.

**Disclaimer:** I'm the maintainer of the javafx-maven-plugin and creator of the javafx-gradle-plugin.

Comment: thanks for your response, I think this description would do it, but I don't know how to make an executable file at the first place, I searched a lot but nothing suits my situation, BTW I included my 'build.gradle' in my question

Comment: Just call `gradle jfxJar` to generate some javafx-executable jar, to create some native launcher/executable just call `gradle jfxNative`. The files will be generated below the `build/jfx/`-folder.